# How can I access a variable inside a render from the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and JS as a whole so forgive me if my question sounds silly.

I have variable that is declared inside a render in react. I would however like to access this variable, either in the state or in a method outside the render. How can this be achieved?

my state:

```
   state = {
        full_name : '',
        id_number : '',
        phone_number : ''
    }
```

my variable:

```
render(){
const phoneNumber = //Code of how I get phone number

  return (
  //JSX here
  )
}
```

I would like to update my state with this phone number.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access it inside render using
`this.state.phone_number` 
If you want to access inside your return statment access in between curly braces.
`{this.state.phone_number}`

Where you can get like this `const phoneNUmber = this.state.phone_number`

if you want to update the phone number state it can be update by following code

```
this.setState({phone_number: new_number});
```

Comment: I am trying to get it from outside the render as I already have it  in the render. When I try to update it with this.setState({phone_number: new_number}), I still get an empty string.

Comment: you can get it outside the render with `this.state.phone_number` or by destructuring the phone_number from the state object like I said earlier. Now if you are getting empty then it means you have not set the state, hence it would returned the initialization value which is an empty.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I can see you do two things, declare `phone number` in state as a key to contain string, and i see another attempt to declare `phone_number` as a const variable. The `phone_number` in the state can be accessed everywhere in the code.

If you are trying to access the global one in the state then,

`const phone_number = //Code of how I get phone number`

to be

`const {phone_number} = this.state`;

this would enable you use `phone_number` anywhere in the render method.

Comment: Just edited, what I need is to access the const phoneNumber from the state. and set its value as the value of the phone_number in the state

Answer (score 0):

```
class Sample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      full_name: "",
      id_number: "",
      phone_number: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { full_name, id_number, phone_number } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
         {full_name} 
         {/* like this way you can access this state value inside the JSX */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Sample;
```